Can you use python xlwings library to trigger VBA code
I have a use case where I want to automate and interface an Excel model from   The workflow would be something like:

Transfer data from Python to Excel
Execute macro to run model model to convergence (about 45secs)
Wait for macro to a cell statues indicating completion.
Collect the data from Excel and post-process in Python

Can I do this with xlwings or any other Excel interface library?

Sure, or win32com.

Probably even be able to use Python code to replace the macro code too if you wanted.

@moken, yes I noticed.  But for my use case translating the VBA to something else would take prohibitive effort at this point.

You could do this by borrowing code from the xloil test runner as per the below. I've assumed that your macro reads data from a sheet called Input and writes to a sheet called Output, but those details are easy to change.  The Run invocation should not return until the macro has finished but I've added a possible wait time should that be required.
As noted in the comments you could do something similar with win32com directly.
with xloil.Application() as app:

    # Need at least one open workbook to get the COM server running properly
    dummy = app.workbooks.add()

    # When running via COM automation, no addins are loaded, so if required
    # they would need to be loaded here.

    app.visible = True

    with app.open("YourFile.xlsm", read_only=True) as wb:

        wb["Input!A1:G100"] = input_data  # input_data is a numpy array

        app.calculate(full=True)

        app.Run("YourFile.xlsm!TheCalcMacro")

        output_data = wb["Output!A1:G100"].value  # output_data will be a numpy array

